# Is it possible to find the Tal'Mahe'Ra blade in the Steam version of Vampire Bloodlines?

Tags: steam, vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

Well, any question about Vampire The Masquerade Bloodlines might be slightly ambiguous because the game may change substantially depending on which version you are playing.

I have played the **Steam** Version - download around November 2011 - four times with different clans but am still unable to find the Tal'Mahe'Ra blade. Can anyone confirm that this weapon will not be available in the Steam version of the game? Or if I am wrong, point me to the location where I can find the blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which specific patch version you're using, it'll be at either right near the entrance of **The Hallowbrook Hotel** downtown, or towards the end of it in Andrei's Lair.

I seem to recall that you need a high **Inspection** skill to notice it however.

Comment: Ok, I do not patch the game separately - and accept whatever Steam gives me.

Comment: Should be right near the entrance to the Hallowbrook then - but I would really discourage running VTM:B without Wesp's patch. It is... a substantial improvement.